# How to update a multiple records in an array with sub dictionary in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update multiple records in an array with in sub dictionary. If where ever that record is found in a collection  that record must be update.

**My mongoose schema like this:**

```
comments: [{
            text: {
                type: String,
            },
            author: {
                id: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'User'
                },
                name: {
                   type:String
                },
                photo:{
                   type:String
                }            
            }
        }]



**My data like this:**




comments : [ 
                {
                    "text" : "Good one",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5722101611a53cca08544d25"),
                    "author" : {
                        "id" : "123",
                        "name" : null,
                        "photo" : null
                    }
                },
                 {
                    "text" : "nice one",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5722103511a53cca08544d24"),
                    "created" : ISODate("2016-04-28T13:29:25.444Z"),
                    "author" : {
                        "id" : "123",
                        "name" :null,
                        "photo":null
                    }
                },
                 {
                "text" : "Good one",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5718768d98eb065c035b645"),
                "author" : {
                    "id" : "456"
                }
            }]
```

I want to update *name and photo* in the the comments array based on the *author.id*. In the above data to update *author.id=123*

**My code is:**

```
Event.find({'comments.author.id':_id},(err,event)=>{
_.each(event,function(eventData){
                  _.each(eventData.comments,function(commentData){
                    if(commentData.author.id ==_id){

                      console.log("event:"+eventData._id)
                       Event.update({_id:eventData._id},{$set:{'comments':[{'author.name':username,'author.photo':photoUrl}]}},{multi:true},(err,updateComment)=>{
                        console.log("commentupdate:"+JSON.stringify(updateComment))
                    });
                    }

                  })   
              })
           })
```

I am stuck here from last two days.Please give me any solution.Don't make it as duplicate, If it is duplicate please provide a valid answer. Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924894/update-object-with-given-id-embed-in-array-without-restructuring-mongo-database/36929918#36929918

Multi will update update multiple documents not sub documents.

Comment: I checked that link and used that code. I got an error like _EventEventSchemaEs62.default.find(...).forEach is not a function.